# How to compare two strings using Tokenization i.e.,strtok() function?

Tags: c++

I know how to tokenize a string using strtok() function.
Now I have data saved in linked lists. If I take input from user using cin.ignore, how would I compare input words with data present in my liked lists. 
PS: the concept is to develop a search engine.

Comment: It would helps if you gave an examples of your input and expected output.

Comment: @ahenderson .. This is just an exapmple I am trying to get. i can easily extend this concept to my desired output. But this is not working properly.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()


{char inputStr[200];

  char str[] ="- This, a sample string.";

  char * pch;

  cin >> inputStr;

  cin.getline(inputStr,200);

  pch = strtok (str," ,.-");

    while (pch != NULL)

    {if (inputStr==pch){
            cout<<"strings matched.."<<endl;}
        printf ("%s\n",pch);
        pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
    }
 return 0;
}

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use strtok.
2. Don't use a linked list.
3. cin.ignore won't get you input from the user.
4. Put your words in a `std::set` (or unordered_set), and look for them with `your_set.find`.

As an aside, I doubt this will be much good for a search engine, except (possibly) for the stop list -- figuring out whether the current word is one you want to ignore. For example, build a list of "a", "an", "the", etc., that aren't worth indexing, and as you index something, check whether it's in that last (and obviously ignore it if it is).

Comment: Actually it is kind of mandatory to use linked lists. As far cin.ignore is concerned that is just for the user input. I can use cin.getline etc....

Comment: @AzkaAhmad: "Kinda mandatory" as in "I will be fired", or as in "nobody's mentioned other choices"? To read a word at a time, you usually just want to use something like `while (your_stream >> your_string) process(your_string);`

Comment: Okay . if I can't use strtok(), what would be next better idea to compare input string to a bunch of data with delimiter "space".

Comment: @AzkaAhmad: if you use `>>` as suggested above, it'll read a word up to the first white space character.